# Calling from Angular JS to web API error: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values, Origin is therefore not allowed access

Tags: c#, angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, cors

1. List item

I have a web API deployed on 'https://example.com/api/gd/alldata', when i run it directly from browser URL it shows the result. but when i call it from other Angular JS application, it is giving me below error.

Error:

Failed to load 'https://example.com/api/gd/alldata' 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:64000, http://localhost:64000, *', 
but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:64000' is therefore not allowed access.

This is my new angularjs service in another application.

```
  var promise = $http({

        method: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://example.com/api/gd/alldata",
        //headers: headers, 
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data)
            return response.data;
        },
        function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
```

Below is my API code already deployed on some link,

i enabled cors in webapiconfig and entry on startup.cs file.

Startup.cs file

```
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

webapiconfig.cs

```
 config.EnableCors();
```

Can you please tell me where i am doing mistake or anything i am missing or doing wrong in my code.

Comment: Where are you hosting your API?

Comment: on azurewebsites.net

Comment: Did you add the CORS setting on your azure's app service?

Comment: no i didnt add the CORS settings on azure. i just added the cors in my website service and deployed it on azure.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: i am testing it. let me tell you in few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are hosting on Azure and calling from localhost (local dev environment), you will have to update the following CORS setting on Azure App Service:

1. Goto your App Service on https://portal.azure.com
2. Search for CORS (press CTRL + /)
3. Add your `localhost:6400` or better yet `*` under **Allowed Origins**
4. Save

[image]